# Homomorphism on U(36)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

**Question**
Suppose that $f$ is homomorphism of $U(36)$, $\ker(f) = \{1,13,25\}$, and $f(5) =17$. Determine all the elements that map to 17.

**What I've tried so far**
So I've determined that $U(36) = \{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35\}$ so $|U(36)| = 12$. Because $\ker(f) \triangleleft U(36)$, and $|\ker(f)| = 3$, then we know that $U(36)/\ker(f)$ is a group of order 12/3 = 4.

However, I'm not sure any of this helps. Any suggestions on how to determine the elements that map to 17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $k \in \ker(f)$, and $g \in U(36)$, then $f(kg) = f(k)f(g) = f(g)$.

To convince yourself that this is the full story of the preimage $f^{-1}(17)$, think about the first isomorphism theorem strictly in terms of sets: It tells you that the cosets $U(36)/\ker(f)$ are in bijection with $\operatorname{Im}(f)$.

Comment: So then because $f(5*13) = f(65)$ is congruent to $f(29)$; and $f(5*25) = f(125)$ is congruent to $f(17)$, this means that the set of elements that map to 17 are $\{5,17,29\}$?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right!